# Trying to loop over hash for Vagrant boxes, failing

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

Ok, i'm very new to Ruby (i come from PHP, Symfony2 and AngularJS) and relatively new when it comes to properly writing Vagrantfiles. I'm trying to create a multi-machine environment while trying to stick to DRY principles.

As i read that Vagrantfiles understand Ruby syntax, i looked up the way Ruby defines associative arrays. This happened to be quite easy, apparently not.

My Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-  
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

#hash for boxes: 'box_name' => 'last_ip_octet'
boxes = {
        'frontend' => '10',
        'qp' => '11'
}


Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

config.vm.box = "chef/ubuntu-14.04"

#All machines, see the hash defined in top of the Vagrantfile for all the boxes
  boxes.each do |key, value|
    config.vm.define "#{key}.qp" do |#{key}_qp|
        #{key}_qp.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.51.#{value}"
        #{key}_qp.vm.provision "shell", path: "../provisioning/agentinstall.sh"
        #{key}_qp.vm.synced_folder "./share/#{key}.qp", "/var/www/html"
    end
  end
end
```

My problem reads as follows:

```
There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

/Users/Zowie/Documents/vagrant/project/temp/Vagrantfile:30: syntax error,           unexpected keyword_end, expecting '|'
end     
   ^
```

Unfortunately, i can't find any info on using Hashes or anything similar in Vagrantfiles. 
I really hope you can help me out, because i'd not feel good while writing a super-long Vagrantfile with a lot of repetitions...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jeeeeeeez, i now notice that the '#' comments out lines in the file. I'll check change it in 30 minutes! If you're reading, please wait a little. Thanks!

Comment: You're right - it's the hash in the `config.vm.define` line that's breaking things.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for confirming it. Answering own question to help anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stackoverflow website answered my question for me!
Thanks to Stackoverflow's code block feature, i noticed that my machine-specific configurations were commented out because i used a '#'.

I fixed it by using the following syntax in my loop (which is also easier to read):

```
  boxes.each do |key, value|
    config.vm.define "#{key}.qp" do |node|
        node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.51.#{value}"
        node.vm.provision "shell", path: "../provisioning/agentinstall.sh"
        node.vm.synced_folder "./share/#{key}.qp", "/var/www/html"
    end
  end
```